# Work with values of multiple file input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have multiple file input. I select five files in it. Can i delete from this input 1 or 2 files and upload? [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wCJuQ/)

**HTML:**

```
<input type="file" id="files" name="files[]"  multiple="multiple" />
```

part of **JS:**

```
function handleFileDelete() {
    $(".thumb").on("click", function(){
        $(this).detach();
    })
}
```

I can delete preview, but how to delete value in input?

Comment: the fiddle seems to be incomplete. I don't see the elements with .thumb class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you cannot: [Remove selected file(s) before upload with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9337793/remove-selected-files-before-upload-with-javascript) as FileList has no api call to remove an item.

However, there is an alternative suggestion here which may help you, it provides an implementation on how to "clear" the file list: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13351234/2469255

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok.. How about another solution - take value of multiple file input(3 images) and send it to 3 hidden file inputs(no multiple) one by one. Then clean multiple input. And do what i want with this hidden imputs - remove, copy.. etc. Question - how to take and write value of multiple file input one be one?

Comment: [This](http://jsfiddle.net/A3KJE/) or [this](http://jsfiddle.net/A3KJE/1/) way i can get names of files. But i think in my case it's useless..

Comment: @WaNgeL I am inclined to agree, without the underlying binary object there's not much you can do with it. `.getAsBinary()` is also obsolete now and as far as I can tell there's no (API) way of getting at it.