# Remove particular image from temp files[0]

Tags: jquery, html

I am using ajax for multiple image upload functionality. I also display the preview of image before uploading. Now when I select 4 images(image1, image2, image3 and image4) and show the preview of them.

Now if I remove one image from selected but its still exist in : **files[0]**

How can I clear particular image from **files[0]**.

I am reading these images from temp via using below code:

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = imageIsLoaded;
reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
console.log(this.files[0]);
```

I just want to unset one particular image ( image1) from multiple images which I have selected for uploads.

Any help would be appreciative.

Comment: what does `this` refers to? and what's `this.files[0]`? Would be helpful if you show more code and `this.files[0]` value as well

Comment: When you upload any image using <input type='file'> then it will store in files[0] and we can read this file using FileReader via creating new object.

Comment: it looks like there is no API for that http://stackoverflow.com/a/9337828/3611180

Answer (score 0):

You can perhaps splice the array of files, something like this.

Example

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     var arr = ["jQuery","JavaScript","HTML","Ajax","Css"];
     var itemtoRemove = "HTML";
     arr.splice($.inArray(itemtoRemove, arr),1);
});​
```

So for your code

```
this.files.splice($.inArray(this.files[0], this.files), 1);
```